# Bash variable expansion in command

Tags: bash

```
DATE="1 week ago"
date --date='$DATE'
```

doesn't work. How can I get it to work?

I could do:

```
DATE_CMD="date --date='$DATE'"
eval $DATE_CMD
```

but I don't want to store the entire command in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a victim of quote expansion.

The proper invocation would likely be:

```
DATE='1 week ago'
date --date="$DATE"
```

(notice the double quotes)

Comment: Wow! That was the quickest solution I've ever received! Can't even accept your answer yet since I have to wait 11 minutes (apparently).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use double-quotes to enable string interpolation:

```
date --date="$date"
```

Comment: Another quick response. Yes, this works too. Thought I'd direct readers to this topic which explains it quite nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash