# Trying to use a wildcard with a variable in SSH comand

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

This will work, when i hard code the name of the file I want to find.

```
ANSWER=`ssh -q username@hostname'ls "/some/directory/location/availablefiles.txt" | wc -l'`
```

It will not work when I try to pass it a variable and a wildcard, like the below example:

For example val=available , so the command should return the file beginning with available, which would be the same as the file in the first example, availablefiles.txt

```
ANSWER=`ssh -q username@hostname 'ls /some/directory/location/"$val"* | wc -l'`
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Isn't it the same as yesterday's http://stackoverflow.com/q/22612016/1983854 ? `ANSWER=$(ssh -q username@hostname "ls /some/directory/location/$val* | wc -l")` should make it.

Comment: @fedorqui yes, and that didnt work, the shell is not seeing the variable

Comment: But because you did not quote properly. It is the whole ssh command what I meant.

Comment: @fedorqui I had the quotes in in the actual script. Stack overflow removed them for some reason. the problem is with the shell not seeing the variable

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: @fedorqui yes. No success! :-(